# Is there anyway to detect if the user successfully sent/share my app link on whatsapp/messenger?

Tags: java, android

I have a function to send my app link on whatsapp/messenger and wanna make sure the user send it to another user.

Comment: No. What the user does in Whatsapp is none of your business.

Comment: i think it's possible on IOS.

Comment: No, it most certainly is not.

Comment: but the most of games do not pay coins to the user if he cancel the send link , right ?

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to detect if the user opened WhatsApp but there is no way to detect inner activity of WhatsApp.
WhatsApp doesn't allow any API.

You can do it using 1 thing, but it is time taking

You can capture the bitmap of whatsapp screen when user clicks on share button. And then save the bitmap in video format on server. Later manually you can watch video to verify if user has sent the data or not. Or you can create a AI tool for verifying video by doing some codes..

Hope this answer help you

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting to know a message has been sent with the link in. The only way to absolutely know is to directly use an api for the messaging service(s). This also forces your app to require many more permissions and expects the user to log on with their *personal* details in *your* app.  I shouldn't need to say this is incredibly bad practice.

The purpose many apps have for rewarding sending links is to encourage users to try it out. Getting users to send links to their own messaging app(s) lets them know how easy it is, and then they may consider letting people know about your app, even if they do not share immediately. These reward systems are not foolproof, in android there are many ways to interfere with and break intents. So just remember these 'coins' are gamification, not payment in a real world currency.